# Chrome extension Attempting to use a disconnected port object manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension where a content script establishes a connection with a service worker using a port, and sends messages via this port. However, I'm encountering a problem when the service worker is terminated due to inactivity, resulting in a "disconnected port object" error when the content script attempts to send a message after the service worker has stopped.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

In the content script:

```
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'myport' });

// Wrapped in a click listener
port.postMessage({ foo: 'bar' });
```

In the service worker:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
  if (port.name === 'myport') {
    port.onMessage.addListener((m) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        port.postMessage({ id: 'back' });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

This setup works fine under normal conditions. However, if the service worker is terminated after 30 seconds of inactivity, and subsequently, the content script attempts to send a message via the port, it throws the error:

> Attempting to use a disconnected port object

And the service worker fails to handle the message.

What can be done to handle this scenario gracefully? How can I ensure that the communication between the content script and the service worker remains robust even after the service worker has been terminated due to inactivity?

It's worth mentioning that I'm using Manifest V3 for this extension.

I attempted to use single messages instead of ports for communication between the content script and service worker, but encountered a similar error. While I'm aware of methods to keep the service worker active indefinitely, I'm inclined towards finding a native solution for this issue.

Comment: This is the intended behavior, the only solution is to send a dummy message every 29 seconds or less to keep the worker alive ([more examples](/a/66618269)).

Comment: How does it make sense? so the service worker is useless if not using hacks

Comment: It's a known problem that Chromium team makes a lot of questionable decisions in ManifestV3 and they ignore the feedback once they make a decision which they consider sensible based on their unrealistic views.